# POST csv file httpclient C# and application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: c#, post, file-upload, console-application, postman

I am trying to implement a working postman POST call, to a c# console application and it is giving me: forbidden 403.
It is calling an API and it is uploading a CSV file.
This is the working call in postman:

[image: postman part 1]

[image: postmnan part2]
I am trying several options. I have acchived until get a 403 forbidden with this code:

```
    HttpClient c = new HttpClient();
    var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\test7.csv"));
    fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = "test7.csv"
    };
    fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/csv");

      var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "secret", "mypassword" }
    };

    HttpContent DictionaryItems = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);

    MultipartContent content = new MultipartContent();
    //content.Add(formData);
    content.Add(DictionaryItems);
    content.Add(fileContent);
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
    var resultado = c.PostAsync("https://www.apiurl,com", content).Result;
```

I think that I am not putting the secret(password) at the correct position.
Any help?

Comment: Just a wild guess - do you have an auth on your server? If so, how do you handle it in your request?

Comment: Thank you, I have the answer. Look at below

Answer (score -1):

I have got the answer. Here:

```
        FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\test7.csv");
        byte[] fileBytes = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
        stream.Close();
        var byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
        byteArrayContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/csv");
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        form.Add(new StringContent("mypassword"), "secret");
        form.Add(byteArrayContent, "file", "testT.csv");
        HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync("https://www.apiurl.com", form).Result;
        httpClient.Dispose();
```